# How to debug WiX installer

Tags: wix

I am adding to build to your WiX installer to include a multi-website deployment based on custom dialog selection.

I am running into this issue when i run in debug mode and not sure how to tackle the problem to find what the issue is, I am getting a Failed to load XML Error:

> MSI (s) (D0:60) [10:25:14:945]: Executing op:
>   ActionStart(Name=ExecXmlFile,,) Action 10:25:14: ExecXmlFile.
>
> MSI (s) (D0:60) [10:25:14:960]: Executing op:
>   CustomActionSchedule(Action=ExecXmlFile,ActionType=3073,Source=BinaryData,Target=ExecXmlFile,CustomActionData=20C:\Program
>   Files\Company Name,
>   Inc\18.4.007\Navigator\bin\hibernate.cfg.xml30//property[@name='connection.connection_string_name']Workbench_PROD2130/
>   + MORE SIMILAR STUFF
>
> MSI (s) (D0:30) [10:25:14:976]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL:
>   C:\Windows\Installer\MSI5E32.tmp, Entrypoint: ExecXmlFile
>
> MSI (s) (D0:B0) [10:25:14:976]: Generating random cookie.
>
> MSI (s) (D0:B0) [10:25:14:976]: Created Custom Action Server with PID
>   3980 (0xF8C).
>
> MSI (s) (D0:8C) [10:25:15:163]: Running as a service.
>
> MSI (s) (D0:8C) [10:25:15:163]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Elevated custom
>   action server.
>
> ExecXmlFile:  Error 0x8007006e: failed to load XML file:

Comment: Does the xml file exist in the path that it's being referenced as? `Inc\18.4.007\Navigator\bin\hibernate.cfg.xml`

Comment: Yes, it is. I am not too sure why making this change in my code made it work: I kept reading to use XmlConfig instead of XmlFile.        `code   <util:XmlConfig Action="create"
                      Id="SetWorkbenchNavEndpointProd"
                      File="[#Navigator.Web.config]"
                      On="install"
                      Value="/[NAVIGATOR_ENDPOINT]"
                    
                      ElementPath="//frameEndpointConfig/frameEndpoints/add[\[]@name='Workbench_PROD'[\]]"/> `

Answer (score 1):

Since your error occurs when running a custom action, I would add a Debugger.Launch(); for C# or s.t. equivalent for other languages at the very start of your custom action method. This would allow you to debug in Visual Studio as usual.

Answer (score -1):

The only advice I can give you is to use [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is a low-level tool for creating and editing MSI file. At least it will validate your msi and show you any errors or warnings it finds.

Comment: If WiX can't load your Xml, then probably any other Xml edit program should fail also. Find (or write) a dumb program that just does an Xml Load and see what errors you get.

Comment: @PhilDW Orca is not an xml edit program. It should look at your msi and tell you what's wrong with it - potentially - and tell you what part has errors. He can create an msi, he just can't run it successfully.

Comment: I've no idea why gbjbaanb is referring to Orca and my comment because I didn't mention it. Just to state what is apparently not obvious, this is nothing to do with MSI files or Orca. The ExecXml call is a custom action, code somebody wrote, and in that code it's trying to load an Xml file and failing. Orca has no way of knowing you have code that can't load a broken Xml file hanging off your MSI file.

Comment: usually the xml file is embedded within the msi file, so its possible Orca can show you what's in there. It was just a suggestion to help him. I don't know why you were talking about "any other xml edit program"

Comment: Again, to state what is apparently again not obvious. The error is failure to load an Xml file. This means that either it cannot find the Xml file (because the custom action parameters that say where it is located are wrong) or the Xml is malformed, in which case any Xml editor-type program that attempts to load it may also fail. These seem reasonable first steps to debug the issue rather than complain about what Orca does and doesn't do.